# About the helicity current

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem, helicity

In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11034 authors introduce a new conserved current for the massless Dirac fermions. This Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{i}{2} (\bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \partial_\mu \psi - \partial_\mu \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi)
$$
is claimed to be invariant in addition to the conventional **vector** and **axial** symmetry, to the **helical** symmetry.

The helicity operator is defined as:
$$
h = \frac{\mathbf{s} \cdot \mathbf{p}}{p}
$$
And the corresponding transformation:
$$
U(1)_H : 
\qquad \psi \rightarrow e^{2 i \alpha_H h} \psi
\qquad \bar{\psi} \rightarrow \bar{\psi}  e^{2 i \alpha_H h}
$$
With the corresponding Noether charge:
$$
J^{\mu}_H = 2 \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu}  h \psi
$$
In the discussion section on the recent conference A.Vainstein pointed out, that there can be only two *local* currents $J_V, J_A$ and any other current is bound to be linear combination of these, or is non-local.

My question is - which option is realised in this case? I would say, that the expression for the helicity operator involved division by the momentum operator, which seems indicate non-locality, but I am not sure.

Comment: For massless fermions, helicity and chirality identify, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am also used to think so, but on the second page - authors say, that they coincide for the particles, whereas for the antiparticles they differ in sign.

Comment: True; can't you combine with*C*?

Comment: @CosmasZachos so the $J_H^{\mu} = 2 \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{5} C\psi$ ? but I do see by far a straighforward way to express it in terms of $J_V, J_A$.

Comment: I don't want to delve into conventions, but $C^{-1} \gamma_5 C$ is worth looking at....

Comment: @CosmasZachos I was trying to elaborate further with the use of $C^{-1} \gamma_5 C = \gamma_5^T$, $C^{-1} \gamma_\mu C = -\gamma_\mu^T$ . And then one can : $\bar{\psi} C C^{-1}\gamma^{\mu} C C^{-1}\gamma^{5} C \psi = \bar{\psi} C  (\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{5})^T \psi$. Further $\bar{\psi} = (\psi^{*})^T \gamma_0, C^{T} = -C, C^{*} = -C^{-1}$, so I  have $(\widehat{\psi})^T (\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{5})^T \psi$, where $\widehat{\psi} = \gamma_0 C \psi^{*}$ but i still don't see anything handy. What should be noted also?